# Fix HTML by replacing apostrophes with backslash apostrophes within apostrophe delimited string

Tags: html, figure

I'm using NoteTab Pro to fix strings of the form

```
'<figure><img src="Picture 1.jpg" width="100%">Nobody's business, ain't goin' there (Jun, 2020) </figure>',
```

to replace the apostrophes within the string with backslash apostrophes for use on a web page. But I can't figure out a regex expression to do this without also replacing the apostrophes at the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Do you mean replacing apostrophes with `&apos;`?

Comment: Maybe change the first and last to ` and then run the replace?

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW: Replacing apostrophes with &apos; would still leave me with the problem of the keeping the apostrophes at the beginning and end of the string, which I need for the HTML tags.
@-A. Meshu: I don't think a ` at the beginning and end would display the images and text on the web page.
I'm looking for a way to replace the ' within the string with \' but keep the ' at the beginning and end.